# Cocoa Autolayout - Why can't I delete or modify the (purple) width constraint on a Text Field?

Tags: cocoa, layout, interface-builder, osx-lion

I'm building a simple application using autolayout, and I've run into a strange situation. I place a Text Field in an empty part of a large open view so it's not affected by anything but the super view, but when I try to modify the "Width" constraint to be >= instead of ==, it creates a new constraint and refuses to modify the old one. I can't delete it, or change any of its attributes, because it just creates a new one.

Here is a comparison of the two constraints, the purple one being the stubborn one, and the blue one being the newly created one.

[image: Constraint comparison]

Why is the purple rounded one not modifiable?

Comment: Do you mean the purple rounded one?

Comment: @Peter Hosey: Sorry, I have some red colour-blindness. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @ChrisCooper - could you explain exactly how you want to lay your window out? While I get the same behaviour as you (in Xcode 4.2.1), I'm not sure if this is actually a problem. When I lay out my Text Fields I generally want them to be constrained by the UI elements around them - either the super view or other surrounding elements.

Comment: @MauriceKelly: After reading your comment, I went back and looked at another example, and it seems that it's possible to change it. It had to do with with fact that there weren't enough other constraints added that the width would ever have to change. When I added more other constraints (such as leading and trailing space), I was then able to alter the purple constraint (in fact, it disappeared and I had to add my own). It just seems strange that you cannot add your own constraints in either order. I see no problem with having constraints that will never be violated. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My problem had to do with with fact that there weren't enough other constraints added that the width would ever be forced to change. When I added more other constraints (such as leading and trailing space), I was then able to alter the purple constraint (in fact, it disappeared and I had to add my own).

It seems strange that you cannot add your own constraints unless there is a possibility of them being broken, but I guess that's the way it's been integrated into IB in some cases.

Answer (score 17):

I have worked around the presence of undeletable-but-unwanted constraints in IB by setting their priority to 1. Doesn't seem like the Right Thing to do, but sometimes I'm not smart enough to be a Cocoa developer.

Comment: Just to add more info,You get purple constraints because IB thinks  the view will be ambiguous with out the constraints. This should be solved by reducing the priority over another valid-wanted constraint. And it is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Lowering the priority of the purple constraints will also make them editable.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar scenario, where there were two multiline labels. Based on the content size, both should resize.

[image: Two multiline labels]

When the first label resized, it was overwriting the second label because the second one had a Vertical Space constraint( "Top Space to SuperView  = 40". it's a system default constraint - purple colour) which I was  not able to delete/modify.

If I tried to modify it as "Top Space to SuperView  >= 40", it'd be changed to a user constraint( blue colour) and a new purple constraint "Top Space to SuperView  = 40" would be created automatically.

I guess this could be the reason:

When I tried to change the constraint to "Top Space to SuperView  >= 40", the label's default position is undefined : >= **doesn't specify a default position**. It specifies only a '**range of positions**'. Then I added a new constraint by selecting both the labels together and setting the space between them as a constant. 
[image: adding constraint between two labels]

Now, since the first label had a definite position (vertical space = 15) from the top border and the second label was 5 points below the first one, the second label got a vertical position defined. I was able to delete the purple vertical space constraint.

Now, if I remove the constraint between the two labels, the second one will no more have the defined position and system will automatically create a purple constraint for the label.

Answer (score -2):

When you right-click on the constraint, select "Promote to user constraint". Next time you click on constraint, you will be able to delete it as now it is in the hands of the user/developer.

Comment: That won't work. When you delete it, the system constraint will re-appear.